# This is not a fish

Tags: word

I'm sure you know how the word 'ghoti' can be interpreted to be pronounced 'fish', by taking the sounds from the words 'cou**gh**,' 'w**o**men' and 'ac**ti**on.'

But can you find a word in which the letters 'wo' are pronounced as a standard 'u' (as in 'hut')?

The word isn't used much nowadays, but fifty years ago it was in common English circulation.

Comment: Isn't "word" itself such a word?

Comment: @personjerry the `o` in `word` is pronounced `u` as in `hut`, but the `wo` in `word` is pronounced `wu`. He's asking for a word where `wo` loses the `w` sound completely

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One such word is

> **[twopence](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/twopence)**, which is pronounced like "tuppence".

Comment: That certainly was very much in circulation 50 years ago.